# API to get the script version?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a way to get the version number managed by "Files\Manage Versions".
It seems there's no such APIs?
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

Otherwise I would do it using get/set user properties.

Comment: If you want your script to be able to get the project version that it is running within then please go "star" @Edo 's corresponding [feature request (#1369)](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1369).  Your star equals a vote for this feature.  (The request is in the official Apps-Script issue tracker, [according](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features) to the official Google Apps Script Support page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way today to programmatically check for the current script's version. You can manually store it and retrieve it that through [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptproperties).

You can also graphically look at this properties via File-->Project Properties. Please log a feature request in your [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) with details on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation.